# PostgreSQL Aggregate data into single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

With the following SQL query which I want to add an array of JSON objects which has data from another table, based on the `posts.liked_by` array:

```sql
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.author, 
  p.content, 
  u2.id, 
  u2.username, 
  p.liked_by AS likedby
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u1 
  ON p.author = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 
  ON u2.id = ANY(p.liked_by)
```

I'm getting the expected output of

```
╔════╤════════╤═════════════╤══════════╤═════════╗
║ id │ author │ content     │ username │ likedby ║
╠════╪════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═════════╣
║ 1  │ 1      │ Lorem Ipsum │ John Doe │ {1, 2}  ║
╚════╧════════╧═════════════╧══════════╧═════════╝
```

Now, I'd like to modify the `likedby` column to be an array of objects with user data, accoring to something along the lines of this:

```
+----+--------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | author | content     | username | liked_by                                                        |
+----+--------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1      | Lorem Ipsum | John Doe | [{id: 1, username: "John Doe"}, {id: 2, username: "Sam Smith"}] |
+----+--------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

with data of the posts table being structured like

```
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | author | content     | author_id | liked_by  |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1      | lorem ipsum | 1         | {1, 2, 3} |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

and the user table being structured as

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
| 1  | John Doe |
+----+----------+
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: from here: `FROM public.posts AS posts,
  public.users`  remove: `,
  public.users`

Comment: @OtoShavadze That just switches the error to the `users` table.
For reference, I changed it to     FROM 
      public.posts AS posts
      LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON users.id = ANY (posts.likedby)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I based the query on a different query for getting the author data from the user table with the author column value along with the post data

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Question has been edited with sample data and the ideal output.

Comment: What is difference between `author` and `author_id` ?

Comment: No difference, simply an error on my part, @OtoShavadze, question edited with the fixed structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for getting aggregated user names for `liked_by` column, you can use subquery with `jsonb_agg()` and `jsonb_build_object()` functions:

```
SELECT posts.*, "user".username as author_name,  
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object("user".id, "user".username)) FROM "user" where "user".id = any(posts.liked_by)  )
FROM posts
INNER JOIN "user"
ON posts.author_id = "user".id
```

http://rextester.com/KMEY13984

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It works with an explicit join (btw it's not good form to mix and match):

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u1 
    ON p.author = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 
    ON u2.id = ANY(p.liked_by)
```

And as to why, from the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN):

> ... JOIN binds more tightly than comma. For example FROM T1 CROSS JOIN
>   T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON condition is not the same as FROM T1, T2 INNER
>   JOIN T3 ON condition because the condition can reference T1 in the
>   first case but not the second.

Comment: This solved the issue with the error, thank you, I have since edited the question to closer reflect what I'd like to do.

Comment: OK but you shouldn't change your question like that, as now the answer is in response to an issue that no longer appears in the question. Either create a new question for how to get results in a certain format, or edit your question without deleting the original issue.